# Selection list to toggle display of mutliple charts in <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts

There are about 20 `div` sections in my webpage.But after choosing **1** and then **2**, the chart of **1**  is keeping displayed. Any ideas on how to tune the js to make charts being displayed as long as I change selection in the list?What technique do I need for this?

html

```
<select id='selectchart'>
  <option value="0">Sales of Jan</option>
  <option value="1">Sales of Feb</option>
  <option value="2">Sales of Mar</option>
</select>

<div style='display:block; width:600px;' id='chart1'></div>
<div style='display:none; width:600px;' id='chart2'></div>
```

js(the codes here just demonstrate turn on the chart but not disappear the other deselected charts.Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectchart').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        $("#chart1").show();
      }
      else if (this.value =='2')
      {
        $("#chart2").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#chart3").show();
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just use `$("#chart").hide();` to hide the other charts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. I also make your function a bit more dynamic

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectchart').on('change', function() {
    $('div[id^="chart"]').hide()
    $("#chart" + this.value).show();
    if(this.value == 0) {$("#chart1").show();}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='selectchart'>
  <option value="0">Sales of Jan</option>
  <option value="1">Sales of Feb</option>
  <option value="2">Sales of Mar</option>
  <option value="3">Sales of Apr</option>
  <option value="4">Sales of May</option>
</select>

<div style='display:block; width:600px;' id='chart1'>chart1</div>
<div style='display:none; width:600px;' id='chart2'>chart2</div>
<div style='display:none; width:600px;' id='chart3'>chart3</div>
<div style='display:none; width:600px;' id='chart4'>chart4</div>
```

Comment: what does this line `$('div[id^="chart"]').hide()` means?
Especially `div[id^="chart"]`

Comment: `div[id^="chart"]` -> The `div` is the element we will select. `[ ]` is to "target" an attribute. `id^="chart"` means that we want all `id`'s that starts with `chart`. So overall, Take all `div`'s that has an `id` that starts with "chart"

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach that I can think of is give all the charts the same class.

```
 <select id='selectchart'>
  <option value="0">Sales of Jan</option>
  <option value="1">Sales of Feb</option>
  <option value="2">Sales of Mar</option>
</select>
<div style='display:block; width:600px;' id='chart0' class="chart">ccccbbb</div>
<div style='display:none; width:600px;' id='chart1' class="chart">aaa</div>
<div style='display:none; width:600px;' id='chart2' class="chart">bbb</div>
```

Then use jquery to hide the class `chart` and show the current chart.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectchart').on('change', function() {
      $(".chart").hide();
      $("#chart"+this.value).show();
    });
});
```

For the problem of changing size just set a fix size for the graphs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //pie chart    
    function drawPie() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['AA', 5],
      ['BB',  0],
      ['CC',  6],
      ['DD',  7],
      ['GG',  8],
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities01',
      height: 200, //Fix the size
      width: 400 //Fix the size
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart0'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nspfr12/3/)

Comment: Just place `$(".chart").hide();` before your `if` statement, then you don't have to repeate it

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thank you for pointing that out. :) Your way is much easier and cleaner.

Comment: @Ayush  Thanks for your fiddle code, but what I encounter now is the other div chart(Feb and Mar) seem to be smaller. How to fix it? See the link below:
[codepad](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/IGHJWVZGRQ)

Comment: @KenyKeny You just have to update the your options to fix a size like `var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities01',
      height: 200,
      width: 400
    };`

Comment: @Ayush Thanks for your replies and modifications.
The google charts did resize regarding to your advises.But some figures on the charts is misaligned. I think I will work on it later.